# Turning a String into a LinkedList and browsing it with recursion

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I'm very new to recursion (and I'm required to use it) and am having some serious logic trouble using one of my search methods. Please see below:

```
//these are methods within a Linked List ADT with StringBuilder functionality
//the goal here is to access the char (the Node data) at a certain index
public char charAt(int index)
{
    if((firstNode == null) || (index < 0) || (index >= length + 1))
    //firstNode is the 1st Node in the Linked List, where the search begins
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Index or FirstNode is null");
        IndexOutOfBoundsException e = new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        throw e;
    }
    else
    {
        char c = searchForChar(firstNode, index);
        return c;
    }
}
private char searchForChar(Node nodeOne, int index)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(nodeOne == null) //basecase --> end
    {
        i = 0;
        System.out.println("nodeOne null, returning null Node data");
        return 'n';
    }
    else if(i == index) //basecase --> found
    {
        i = 0;
        return nodeOne.data; //nodeOne.data holds the char in the Node
    }
    else if(nodeOne != null) //search continues
    {
        searchForChar(nodeOne.next, index);
        i++;
        return nodeOne.data;
    }
    return nodeOne.data;
}
```

The output is length-1 prints of "nodeOne null, returning null Node data". I don't understand how the recursive statement in the last else-if statement if being reached when it seems like the null statement in the first if statement is being reached as well.

I tried rearranging the if statements so that the `if(nodeOne != null)` is first, but that gives me a `NullPointerException`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Especially because I can print the data in the Nodes using a `toString()` method so I know the Nodes don't have null data.

Can anyone please help me understand?

Comment: I guess you would have a way better chance to get a meaningful answer/suggestion here, if you posted a complete example - e.g. a program someone can run. I suggest you add an example of how you call these methods and how does the outcome differ from what you expect.

Comment: Where does *firstNode* come from?

Comment: I've made some edits explaining some of what the class, methods, and variables are/are meant to do - I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `i` and use `return rearchForChar(nodeOne.next, index - 1);` and check if for `index == 0`, because then you know you are at the right node.

Comment: @martijnn2008 but shouldn't index stay the same since the point of the 2 methods is to find a char at that particular index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a complete example I hope this is what you need. If you would loop over the string `StackOverflow` with `i < 14` it will also print the null character `\0` if you would use `i < 15` it will give you a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. By reducing index by 1 every time you are actually saying I need to `(index - 1)` hops to my destination node.

```
public class CharTest {
    public static class Node {
        private char content;
        private Node nextNode;

        public Node () {
            content = '\0';
            nextNode = null;
        }

        public Node (String str) {
            Node temp = this;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                temp.content = str.charAt(i);
                temp.nextNode = new Node();
                temp = temp.nextNode;
            }
        }

        public char charAt(int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return content;
            } else if (index < 0 || nextNode == null) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            return nextNode.charAt(index - 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node test = new Node("StackOverflow");
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) { 
            System.out.print(test.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

I will leave making a `toString()` method either iteratively or recursively an exercise to the reader. But using a `StringBuilder` or a `char[]` would be a good idea, because of a performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much! You didn't have to write out all the code, but I appreciate it anyway. I wouldn't take your code - I'm just hear to understand what I'm doing, my mistakes, and how to be a better programmer. I also only just this morning realized that I had a loop in my main printing length-1 of the charAt() outputs. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer and use the code in any way :). Best of luck.

Comment: I adapted the code in your charAt method to my class and methods and it works brilliantly! Thanks so much for pushing me in the right direction!